# If $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ continuous and $X_s$ a continuous process, is $s\mapsto f(X_s)$ continuous in $L^2$?

Tags: probability

Let $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ a probability space. I know that when $t\mapsto f(t,\omega )$ is continuous in $L^2$ then the Riemann-Stiljes

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(t_{j-1},\cdot )(B_{t_j}-B_{t_{j-1}})$$
converges in $L^2$ to Itô integral $\int_0^T f(t,\omega )dB_t(\omega )$ for all partition $0=t_0<t_1<...<t_n=T$.

If $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is continuous and $X_s$ is a a.s. continuous process, if $f(X_s)\in L^2(\mathbb P\otimes \lambda )$ where $\lambda $ is the lebesgue measure on $[0,T]$, is $s\mapsto f(X_s)$ continuous in $L^2$ ? And thus $$\sum_{i=1}^n f(X_{t_{i-1}})(B_{t_{i}}-B_{t_{i-1}})$$
converges to the Itô integral $\int_0^T f(X_s)dB_s$.

---

The problem is I can't do better than $$\mathbb P\{|f(X_{s+h})-f(X_s)|>\varepsilon \}\leq \frac{\mathbb E\Big[|f(X_{s+h})-f(X_s)|^2\Big]}{\varepsilon ^2},$$
which is quite useless.

Comment: $f(X_s)$ may not belong to $L^{2}$ even if $X_s$ belongs to  $L^{2}$ for every $s$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: yes, I agree. I edited my question (I add $f(X_s)\in L^2$